# Multiple test in vert.x application

Tags: scala, vert.x

Hello and happy new year

I am working with Vert.x & Scala on API application. I am using the code example from this [page](http://vertx.io/blog/scala-is-here/) to create a first basic API application.

My problem is, that I have two tests on the same address & port, but not on the same route, but only one is ran. For the other, the IDE return

```
VerticleSpec *** ABORTED ***
[info]   java.net.BindException: Address already in use
[info]   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
[info]   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
[info]   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
[info]   at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
[info]   at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:128)
[info]   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:558)
[info]   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1283)
[info]   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501)
[info]   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486)
[info]   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:989)
```

So, how could I make all my tests running ?

EDIT
Under is one file coming from the official repo. It deploy and undeploy route of the API. So, that means the port should be taken then released after one test, right ?

```
import io.vertx.lang.scala.json.{Json, JsonObject}
import io.vertx.lang.scala.{ScalaVerticle, VertxExecutionContext}
import io.vertx.scala.core.{DeploymentOptions, Vertx}
import org.scalatest.{AsyncFlatSpec, BeforeAndAfter}

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

abstract class VerticleTesting[A <: ScalaVerticle: TypeTag] extends AsyncFlatSpec with BeforeAndAfter{
  val vertx = Vertx.vertx
  implicit val vertxExecutionContext = VertxExecutionContext(
    vertx.getOrCreateContext()
  )

  private var deploymentId = ""

  def config(): JsonObject = Json.emptyObj()

  before {
    deploymentId = Await.result(
      vertx
        .deployVerticleFuture("scala:" + implicitly[TypeTag[A]].tpe.typeSymbol.fullName,
          DeploymentOptions().setConfig(config()))
        .andThen {
          case Success(d) => d
          case Failure(t) => throw new RuntimeException(t)
        },
      10000 millis
    )
  }

  after {
    Await.result(
      vertx.undeployFuture(deploymentId)
        .andThen {
          case Success(d) => d
          case Failure(t) => throw new RuntimeException(t)
        },
      10000 millis
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Not possible, a limitation where a PC can only open a single port at a time. Are there issues to run a single test after another?

Comment: I added the content of one file, which is used to make test run on after each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found how do it.

In the build.sbt, I just added this line, and it worked fine

```
parallelExecution in Test := false
```

So, if somebody got this problem, it could help :)